# React doesn't render form autofill suggestions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I'm using react to create a panel to add a new product. I've created a separate auto-complete class which is supposed to render an input element and a list of suggested autofill items underneath. The input element shows but not the autofill suggestions. Have a look at the code

Autofill class

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import firebase from "../Firebase";

export default class AutoCompleteDistID extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      sellerName: [],
      sellerId: [],
      suggestions: [],
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    var sellerRef = firebase.database().ref().child("Sellers");
    sellerRef.once("value", (snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach((childSnap) => {
        var distrName = childSnap.val().sellerName;
        var distrId = childSnap.val().sellerName.sellerId;
        // var distrName = [{ name: data.sellerName }];
        this.setState((prevState) => {
          return {
            sellerName: [...prevState.sellerName, distrName],
            sellerId: [...prevState.sellerId, distrId],
            suggestions: [...prevState.suggestions, distrName],
          };
        });
      });
    });
  }

  onTextChange = (e) => {
    var sellerNames = [this.state.sellerName];
    const value = e.target.value;
    let newSuggestions = [];
    if (value.length > 0) {
      const regex = new RegExp(`^${value}`, "i");
      newSuggestions = sellerNames.sort().filter((v) => regex.test(v));
    }

    this.setState(() => ({ newSuggestions }));
  };

  renderSuggestions() {
    const newSuggestions = this.state.suggestions;
    if (newSuggestions.length === 0) {
      return null;
    }
    return (
      <ul>
        {newSuggestions.map((item) => (
          <li>{item}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input onChange={this.onTextChange} />
        {this.renderSuggestions}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Main form

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import firebase from "../Firebase";
import AutoCompleteDistID from "./AutoCompleteDistID";

export default class Products extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      description: "",
      prodQty: "",
    };

    this.pushProduct = this.pushProduct.bind(this);
  }

  handleFormChange = (event) => {
    const target = event.target;
    const colName = target.name;
    this.setState({
      [colName]: event.target.value,
    });
  };

  pushProduct() {
    const userRef = firebase.database().ref().child("Users"); //Get reference to Users DB
    const prodData = this.state;
    userRef.push(prodData);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <br />
        <form style={{ border: "solid", borderWidth: "1px", width: "600px" }}>

          <br />
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.prodQty}
            placeholder="Available Quantity"
            onChange={this.handleFormChange}
            name="prodQty"
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.description}
            placeholder="Description"
            onChange={this.handleFormChange}
            name="description"
          />
          <AutoCompleteDistID />
          <br />
          <br />
        </form>
        <button onClick={this.pushProduct} type="button">
          Add Product
        </button>
        <br />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

State variable is `suggestions` but you are setting `newSuggestions`.

```
onTextChange = (e) => {
    var sellerNames = [this.state.sellerName];
    const value = e.target.value;
    let newSuggestions = [];
    if (value.length > 0) {
      const regex = new RegExp(`^${value}`, "i");
      newSuggestions = sellerNames.sort().filter((v) => regex.test(v));
    }
    // HERE IS THE MISTAKE
    this.setState(() => ({ suggestions: newSuggestions }));
  };
```

In `AutoCompleteDistID` render method

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input onChange={this.onTextChange} />
        {this.renderSuggestions()}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: I fixed what you mentioned but unfortunately the suggested items still don't show. I can confirm that the suggested item array gets populated though

Comment: Please update your code as there are many typos. `value` not set to input box also function call is incorrect.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to react so I might have made some errors, I'll try sorting them out but can you elaborate a little on the wrong function call

Comment: Updates\d my answer, this will solve your problem :)